# Calculate probability through area

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, conditional-probability

I know that to calculate a probability looking at a graph we have to use an integral (when required).
Thing is, on this question I'm having a hard time on how to figure it out how to get the answer.

I'll start by presenting the image:

[image: Picture]

The goal is to calculate $P(X > 2 | X < 7)$, which morphs into: $P(X > 2$ AND $X < 7) / P(X < 7)$

I know how to get the areas of the triangle and all that, but how can I get the $P(2 < X < 3)$?

Thank you.

Comment: Given a pdf $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ like the one you've provided, probability is computed as $\operatorname P(a<X<b) = \int_a^bf(x)\mathrm dx$, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: Exactly, but I don't have f(x), so what should it be?

Comment: $f(x)$ is the equation of the line which extends from $x = 0$ to $x = 3$. You have two known points on the line, i.e., $(0, 0)$ and $(3, a)$. Using these, you should be able to find the equation.

Comment: In this case, $f(x)$ is provided pictorially, so the idea is to interpret $\int_2^3f(x)\mathrm dx$ pictorially also; that is, as an area under the curve. Since the plot is comprised of triangles and rectangles, you can do this directly; alternatively, you can determine the equations for the line segments that define it and proceed accordingly

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to find the required area by subtracting the area of the triangle with the base from $0\le x\le 2$ from the triangle with the base from $0\le x \le 3$. _Hint:_ Similar triangles.

Comment: Thank you to both of you.
I calculated the line (y = a/3*x) and then it was easy to get the definite integral.

Really rusty on this stuff, but then again, thank you both